# How to obtain counts and sums for pairs of values in each row of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Problem:**

I have a `DataFrame` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name":["john","jim","eric","jim","john","jim","jim","eric","eric","john"],
    "category":["a","b","c","b","a","b","c","c","a","c"],
    "amount":[100,200,13,23,40,2,43,92,83,1]
})
```

```
    name    | category  | amount
    ----------------------------
0   john    | a         | 100
1   jim     | b         | 200
2   eric    | c         | 13
3   jim     | b         | 23
4   john    | a         | 40
5   jim     | b         | 2
6   jim     | c         | 43
7   eric    | c         | 92
8   eric    | a         | 83
9   john    | c         | 1
```

I would like to add two new columns: first; the total `amount` for the relevant `category` for the `name` of the row (eg: the value in row `0` would be `140`, because `john` has a total of `100 + 40` of the `a` `category`). Second; the counts of those `name` and `category` combinations which are being summed in the first new column (eg: the row `0` value would be `2`).

**Desired output:**

The output I'm looking for here looks like this:

```
    name    | category  | amount    | sum_for_category  | count_for_category
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   john    | a         | 100       | 140               | 2
1   jim     | b         | 200       | 225               | 3
2   eric    | c         | 13        | 105               | 2
3   jim     | b         | 23        | 225               | 3
4   john    | a         | 40        | 140               | 2
5   jim     | b         | 2         | 225               | 3
6   jim     | c         | 43        | 43                | 1
7   eric    | c         | 92        | 105               | 2
8   eric    | a         | 83        | 83                | 1
9   john    | c         | 1         | 1                 | 1
```

I don't want to group the data by the features because I want to keep the same number of rows. I just want to tag on the desired value for each row.

**Best I could do:**

I can't find a good way to do this. The best I've been able to come up with is the following:

```
names = df["name"].unique()
categories = df["category"].unique()

sum_for_category = {i:{
    j:df.loc[(df["name"]==i)&(df["category"]==j)]["amount"].sum() for j in categories
} for i in names}
df["sum_for_category"] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_for_category[x["name"]][x["category"]],axis=1)

count_for_category = {i:{
    j:df.loc[(df["name"]==i)&(df["category"]==j)]["amount"].count() for j in categories
} for i in names}
df["count_for_category"] = df.apply(lambda x: count_for_category[x["name"]][x["category"]],axis=1)
```

But this is extremely clunky and slow; far too slow to be viable on my actual dataset (roughly 700,000 rows x 10 columns). I'm sure there's a better and faster way to do this... Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['name', 'category'])['amount']
df['sum_for_category'] = g.transform('sum')
df['count_or_category'] = g.transform('size')
```

output:

```
   name category  amount  sum_for_category  count_or_category
0  john        a     100               140                  2
1   jim        b     200               225                  3
2  eric        c      13               105                  2
3   jim        b      23               225                  3
4  john        a      40               140                  2
5   jim        b       2               225                  3
6   jim        c      43                43                  1
7  eric        c      92               105                  2
8  eric        a      83                83                  1
9  john        c       1                 1                  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
g = df.groupby(['name', 'category']).amount.agg(['sum','count']).reset_index()
df.merge(g, on = ['name', 'category'], how = 'left')
```

Output:

```
   name category  amount  sum  count
0  john        a     100  140      2
1   jim        b     200  225      3
2  eric        c      13  105      2
3   jim        b      23  225      3
4  john        a      40  140      2
5   jim        b       2  225      3
6   jim        c      43   43      1
7  eric        c      92  105      2
8  eric        a      83   83      1
9  john        c       1    1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name":["john","jim","eric","jim","john","jim","jim","eric","eric","john"],
    "category":["a","b","c","b","a","b","c","c","a","c"],
    "amount":[100,200,13,23,40,2,43,92,83,1]
})
    df_Count = 
df.groupby(['name','category']).count().reset_index().rename({'amount':'Count_For_Category'}, axis=1)
df_Sum = df.groupby(['name','category']).sum().reset_index().rename({'amount':'Sum_For_Category'},axis=1)
df_v2 = pd.merge(df,df_Count[['name','category','Count_For_Category']],  left_on=['name','category'], right_on=['name','category'], how='left')
df_v2 = pd.merge(df_v2,df_Sum[['name','category','Sum_For_Category']],  left_on=['name','category'], right_on=['name','category'], how='left')
df_v2
```

Hi There,

Use a simple code to easy understand, please try these code below, Just run it you will get what you want.

Thanks
Leon